# Nested has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have separate classes Article, User and Image

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I would like to find all images from all users relating to a particular article.

```
imgs = article.users.images
```

Is there a way to recurse into the list of users to extract and concatenate all of the images?

Comment: Made the question clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :images, through: :users
end
```